# Golang / Google Cloud Error Reporting Not Working

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-error-reporting

Problem: When I attempt to use the Error Reporting function to log errors, it doesn't send to the error reporter.

[Here is the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/go)

I instantiate like this:

```golang
const projectID = "correct-project-id"

var ErrorClient *errorreporting.Client

func MakeErrorReporter() {
    var err error
    ctx := context.Background()
    ErrorClient, err = errorreporting.NewClient(ctx, projectID, errorreporting.Config{
        ServiceName: "easyLanding",
        OnError: func(err error) {
            log.Printf("Could not log error: %v", err)
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("this is the fatal err", err.Error())
        log.Fatal(msg)
    }
    defer ErrorClient.Close()
}
```

And then I call it like this:

```
func LogErr(err error, location string, userId uint) string {
    errCode := RandStringRunes(4)
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("Code: %v | Error: %v | Location: %v", errCode, err.Error(), location)
    var email string
    if userId == 0 {
        email = "system"
    } else {
        email, _ = GetUserEmail(userId)
    }
    if viper.GetString("debug") == "false" {
        logger.Logger.Error().Msgf("Just ran the error with client %v", errorReporting.ErrorClient.Report)
        if errorReporting.ErrorClient == nil {
            logger.Logger.Error().Msg("Error client is nil")
        } else {
            logger.Logger.Error().Msg("Error client is NOT nil")
        }
        email = fmt.Sprintf("%s - %s", email, location)
        errorReporting.ErrorClient.Report(errorreporting.Entry{
            Error: err,
            User:  email,
        })
        label := map[string]string{}
        label["key"] = "simpleMessage"
        logger.InfoLogger.Log(logging.Entry{
            Severity: logging.Info,
            Payload:  msg,
            Labels:   label,
            InsertID: "",
        })
    } else {
        logger.Logger.Error().Msg(msg)
        logger.Logger.Error().Msg(email)
    }
    return errCode
}
```

The logs `Error client is NOT nil` runs, so I know it's started, but no alerts come up. I also trigger it through a special URL endpoint that logs an error (or should) on every hit.

Comment: What do you think `defer ErrorClient.Close()` does?

Comment: Hmmmmmnnn.. Probably makes it not work... I'll report back. Thanks

Comment: @EmilePels I removed it and it still does not work.

Comment: Where is your code running? on local device or in a  google google service?

Comment: It's on App Engine Flexible @JanHernandez

Comment: Did you enable the [error reporting API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/overview)? and can you add your app.yaml file?

Comment: @JanHernandez It was the API. Thanks so much! If you care to, comment it below and I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your code on my side and all works as expected, if you can't see any error on GCP console,this indicates that the Error reporting API is not enabled and for this reason you can't see any error on it.

Please enable [Error Reporting API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/overview)